# env not reading variables in ./profile on new session

Tags: macos, path, environment-variables, bash

I might be doing something very wrong here, but when I edit my `.profile` file and I set a new `PATH` variable I am not able to see it set when I start a new session.

So after saving the `.profile` file I open a new terminal window, type `env` and the variables are not there.

What is it that I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ".profile" is only read when invoked as a login shell.  You could try putting these variables in your ".bashrc" file.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried your suggestion. Same results, env's are not there when I run a new terminal session.